# How to delete selected tables using persistentStoreCoordinator

Tags: ios, core-data, nspersistentstore

I'm currently working on an IOS app which is already developed using objective-C.
I have added a module where users when login store details about the user. But as the app is already having some code, when I press the logout button it deletes all the entities from the database. For this they are using something like the code below.

NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];

```
NSError *error = nil;

// retrieve the store URL

NSURL *storeURL = [[managedObjectContext persistentStoreCoordinator] URLForPersistentStore:[[[managedObjectContext persistentStoreCoordinator] persistentStores] lastObject]];

// lock the current context

[managedObjectContext lock];

[managedObjectContext reset];//to drop pending changes

//delete the store from the current managedObjectContext

if ([[managedObjectContext persistentStoreCoordinator] removePersistentStore:[[[managedObjectContext persistentStoreCoordinator] persistentStores] lastObject] error:&error]){

    // remove the file containing the data

    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:storeURL error:&error];

    //recreate the store like in the  appDelegate method

    [[managedObjectContext persistentStoreCoordinator] addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error];//recreates the persistent store

}

[managedObjectContext unlock];
```

By keeping the break points, I understood that they are retrieving the url of the database and deleting it and re-creating it. Lets say they have 3 tables A,B and C, I want to delete A & B but not C. [Reference- Persistent Store Coordinator](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Devpedia-CoreData/persistentStoreCoordinator.html)

Is my understanding correct? How can I achieve this?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did something like below. Correct me If I'm wrong with my approach.

```
    - (void) deleteData {

        NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
        NSError *error = nil;

        [managedObjectContext lock];
        [managedObjectContext reset];
        NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *psc = [managedObjectContext persistentStoreCoordinator];
        NSManagedObjectModel *managedModel = [psc managedObjectModel];
        NSArray *allEntityNames = [managedModel.entitiesByName allKeys];

        for(NSString *entityName in allEntityNames)
        {
//I wanted to delete all objects except for one table
            if(![entityName isEqual:switchAccountsTableName])
            {
                NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
                NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityName inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
                [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
                NSError *objError = nil;
                NSArray *fetchedObjects = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&objError];
                if(fetchedObjects == nil)
                {
                    NSLog(@"Logout- Couldnt delete entity objects");
                }
                for(NSManagedObject *entityObj in fetchedObjects)
                {
                    [managedObjectContext deleteObject:entityObj];
                }
            }
        }
        [managedObjectContext save:&error];
        [managedObjectContext unlock];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When user tap logout, you should clear the stored data.

First of all Fetch all the data using simple fetch store it in an array say "results"

then fetch objects in the array and remove it

```
for (Entity *entityOBJ in results) {
    [context deleteObject:entityOBJ];
}
[context save:&error];
```

You have 3 tables, repeat it for 3 tables. Create a function just pass on the TableName.

Comment: so in the above code(question) they are simply deleting and recreating the entire db?? And in your answer, should it not be `deleteObject:entityOBJ`?

Comment: Thanks for modifying. But how can I delete all entities(in this case A & B) except C?

Comment: Create a function, pass table name and call it for all 3 tables

Comment: oh ok. Thanks. Will give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
  [context deleteObject:managedObject];

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Can't Delete! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
        return;
    }
```

Comment: Using this, you are trying to delete all the objects right?

Comment: no just pass the managedObject of selected cell for index path